# Plotting the 3D conditional function in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, matplotlib

I need to make a 3D plot with the condition that in area of the grid where (x-(M/2))^2+(y-(N/2))^2 < r it draws the paraboloid, in the other grid points there is a flat plane.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

M=70
N=70
r=(N/2)**2

def f(x, y):
    if (x-(M/2))**2+(y-(N/2))**2<r:
        return (x-(M/2))**2/122.5+(y-(N/2))**2/122.5
    return 10.0

x = np.linspace(0, 70, M)
y = np.linspace(0, 70, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
plt.show()
```

But there is some kind of mistake with this condition, so I get:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Please, help me to make this conditional work.

Comment: Is `[1, 5, 0]` greater or smaller than `3`? Read on `numpy.where`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that you compare an array (the result of `(x-(M/2))**2+(y-(N/2))**2` againt a scalar value `r = 1225`.

This result is an array of boolean, which cannot be used as is as a condition (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063039/4373898)).

As advised by @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, you should use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) in this case.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

M=70
N=70
r=(N/2)**2

def f(x, y):
    computed = (x-(M/2))**2+(y-(N/2))**2
    return np.where(computed < r, r / 122.5, 10.0)

x = np.linspace(0, 70, M)
y = np.linspace(0, 70, N)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
plt.show()
```